# wxPython wx.ScrolledWindow insert wx.Panel

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets

I am trying to insert a wx.Panel into a wx.ScrolledWindow. I have a wx.Panel object named self.entTitle that have two input fields for Title and Date. I have a few other objects I want to add in the scrolledwindow, but I want to get this one working first before I go on to the others. Here is my code:

main.py

```
import wx
from EntryScrollPanel import EntryScrollPanel

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, ID, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, ID, title=title, size=(850,725))

        # Creating Panels
        self.main = wx.Panel(self)
        # Create a notebook on the panel
        self.nb = wx.Notebook(self.main, 1)

        # create the page windows as children of the notebook
        entryPg = EntryScrollPanel(self.nb, wx.ID_ANY, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, style=wx.VSCROLL)

        # add the pages to the notebook with the label to show on the tab
        self.nb.AddPage(self.userFCode, "FCodes")

        # Create sizers
        self.mainSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        # Adding Objects to mainSizer
        self.mainSizer.AddSpacer(10)
        #self.mainSizer.Add(self.mainLogin, 1, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND)
        self.mainSizer.Add(self.nb, 1, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND)

        # Set main sizer
        self.main.SetAutoLayout(True)
        self.main.SetSizer(self.mainSizer)
        self.mainSizer.Fit(self.main)
        self.Layout()
        self.Centre(wx.BOTH)
        self.Show()

app = wx.App(False)
frame = MyFrame(None, -1, 'App UI')
app.MainLoop()
```

EntryScrollPanel.py

```
import wx
from titlePanel import titlePanel

class EntryScrollPanel(wx.ScrolledWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent, ID, pos, size, style):
        #self.SetScrollRate( 5, 5 )

        self.entryPgBox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        #self.entTitle = titlePanel(self, -1) i've tried this as well with no success
        self.entTitle = titlePanel(wx.Panel, -1)

        self.entryPgBox.AddSpacer(10)
        self.entryPgBox.Add(self.entTitle, 0, wx.EXPAND)
        self.entryPgBox.AddSpacer(10)

        self.SetAutoLayout(True)
        self.SetSizer(self.entryPgBox)
        self.entryPgBox.Fit(self)
```

titlePanel.py

```
import wx

class titlePanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent, ID):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent, ID)
        titleSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)

        titleLbl = wx.StaticText(self, label="Title: ")
        titleTxt = wx.TextCtrl(self, size=(140,-1))
        dateLbl = wx.StaticText(self, label="Date: ")
        dateCal = wx.DatePickerCtrl(self, wx.DP_DROPDOWN)

        titleSizer.Add(titleLbl,0,wx.EXPAND)
        titleSizer.Add(titleTxt,1,wx.EXPAND)
        titleSizer.Add(dateLbl,0,wx.EXPAND)
        titleSizer.Add(dateCal,0,wx.EXPAND)
```

This is the error I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/JLP_COM1/PycharmProjects/wxPython/wxPythonHelloWorld.py", line 283, in <module>
    frame = MyFrame(None, -1, 'Small editor')
  File "C:/Users/JLP_COM1/PycharmProjects/wxPython/wxPythonHelloWorld.py", line 71, in __init__
    entryPg = EntryScrollPanel(self.nb, wx.ID_ANY, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, style=wx.VSCROLL)
  File "C:\Users\JLP_COM1\PycharmProjects\wxPython\EntryScrollPanel.py", line 17, in __init__
    self.entTitle = titlePanel(self, -1)
  File "C:\Users\JLP_COM1\PycharmProjects\wxPython\titlePanel.py", line 5, in __init__
    wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent, ID)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\wx-3.0-msw\wx\_windows.py", line 68, in __init__
    _windows_.Panel_swiginit(self,_windows_.new_Panel(*args, **kwargs))
TypeError: in method 'new_Panel', expected argument 1 of type 'wxWindow *'
```

How do I add self.entTitle to EntryScrollPanel?

Thank you for any and all help!

Comment: please add the complete traceback. The traceback refers to a method 'new_Panel' that is not included in your code.

Comment: I added the complete traceback.

Comment: Please see edit. If this doesnt fix the issue you should make the effort of posting the most simplified executable code producing your error for us to test. otherwise it is difficult to know where the problem is

Comment: I did, that is why I said look at the edit. I am showing the main.py, if I show any more code it would be irrelevant to my question. Replacing wx.Panel with self generates the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Panel is not an wxWindow so that:

```
self.entTitle = titlePanel(wx.Panel, -1)
```

doesn't work and produces the traceback.
The above code is instantiating an wx.Panel subclass (titlePanel) and sending an wx.Panel as the parent for its constructor in:

```
class titlePanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent, ID):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent, ID)
```

but a Panel needs a window (p.e. a Frame) as parent.

Thus you must do instead:

```
self.entTitle = titlePanel(self, -1)
```

as self, here, the parent of TitlePanel, is a wx.ScrolledWindow

Also note you did not initialized your ScrolledWindow:

```
class EntryScrollPanel(wx.ScrolledWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent, ID):
        wx.ScrolledWindow.__init__(self, parent, ID)    <--- addd this
```

Comment: Can you look at the code for me? It’s also a question about scrollbars.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51169306/add-scrollbars-in-wxpython-but-it-doesnt-appear